# knockout.js checked binding is not working with bootstrap data-toggle="toggle"

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I am using bootstrap toggle here is the html code

```
<input data-bind="checked: Active" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="danger" type="checkbox">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: AddEditSubCategory">Save</button>
```

The checked binding is not working.
here is the knockout.js code

```
var SubCategoryViewModel = {
Active: ko.observable(),
AddEditSubCategory: function () {
        console.log(SubCategoryViewModel.Active());
}
```

I am getting an undefined value in console

```
$(document).ready(function () {
ko.applyBindings(SubCategoryViewModel, document.getElementById("categoryMain"));}
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue.

The design of checkbox is like below image and I, am using this library http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ . If I, don't use data-toggle="toggle" the binding is working perfectly.

[image: image desing]

Comment: You are not defining getCategoryList in your model.

Comment: that is not required.If I checked and unchecked the check box I want the value in active observable property. I am getting an undefined value

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I haven't use jsfiddle. I don't know how to create.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle with what you've posted so far. It seems to be working as intended so the problem must be in a different part of your code. You'll have to show more of it.
https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/mcvga0y9/

Comment: I am facing the problem when I use data-toggle="toggle". Can you check the problem I have added more details

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? When do you get the undefined error?

Comment: I just need the checkbox value .On button click I, am getting an undefined value of checkbox. I have added the button code. Please have a look

Comment: @JasonSpake - If you add https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css and https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js . The solution is not working in jsfiddle

Comment: Bootstrap is probably overwriting the input element which means the checked binding won't work. You'll have to make a custom binding to apply the bootstrap class and update the observable. There are a few examples out there if you google "Knockout binding for Bootstrap toggle buttons"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned by Jason Spake you will need a custom binding.  here is a working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/MBLP9/358/

here is the binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapToggleOn = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $elem = $(element);
        $(element).bootstrapToggle({
        on: 'Yes',
        off: 'No',
        onstyle: 'primary',
        offstyle: 'danger'
        });
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())){
          $elem.bootstrapToggle('on')
        }else{
           $elem.bootstrapToggle('off')
        }

      $elem.change(function() {
       if ($(this).prop('checked')){
          valueAccessor()(true);
       }else{
           valueAccessor()(false);
       }
    })

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var vStatus = $(element).prop('checked');
        var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
            $(element).bootstrapToggle('toggle')
        }
    }
};
```